# Modify values in random rows of a data.table by category

Tags: r, random, data.table

I have a data.table with two columns, let's say city and score

```
data.table(city = sample(c("Cape Town", "New York",  "Tel Aviv"),size=15, replace = TRUE), score = sample(x=1:10, size = 15, replace=TRUE))
         city score
 1:  Tel Aviv     5
 2:  New York     5
 3:  New York     8
 4: Cape Town    10
 5:  Tel Aviv     7
 6:  New York    10
 7:  Tel Aviv     8
 8: Cape Town     2
 9:  Tel Aviv     2
10: Cape Town     2
11: Cape Town     5
12:  New York     1
13:  Tel Aviv     3
14: Cape Town     6
15:  New York     5
```

I want to change the score to 0 to two random rows per city (i.e., 2 rows for Tel Aviv, two for New York, etc.). Please mind that there will always be more than two rows for every city (my real data are quite large...). Ideally, I would like a solution based on data.table commands... 
Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We take the `sample` of number of rows (`.N`) per each 'city' and get the row index (`.I`).  Using that row index as `i`, we assign (`:=`), the 'score' corresponding to that index as '0'.

```
 i1 <- dt[, .I[sample(.N, 2)], by = city]$V1
 dt[i1, score:=0L]
```

In cases where the 'city' have only a single row, I am not sure whether we want to replace that single row with '0' or not. If we are replacing with '0'

```
  i1 <- dt[, if(.N<2) .I else .I[sample(.N,2)] ,city]$V1
  dt[i1, score:=0L]
```

If we don't want to change 'score' for 'city' that have less than 2 rows,

```
  i1 <- dt[, if(.N>1) .I[sample(.N,2)] ,city]$V1
  dt[i1, score := 0L]
```

Or as @Frank commented, we can get the `sample` on `.I` instead of wrapping with `.I` (here we are also changing the scores for nrows in 'city' < 2)

```
  i1 <- dt[, if(.N<2) .I else sample(.I, 2) ,city]$V1
  dt[i1, score := 0L]
```

Comment: @User800701  I have doubt about 'city' that have less than 2 row ie a single row.  What do you want to do for them?  Replace that single row as 0 or leave it as such.

Comment: Actually, for my case, having a single row for any city is not probable. But, just as an exercise, I would replace that single row...

Comment: @User800710 Thanks, I updated with each of those cases.